# boost bind additional arguments to CameraSubscriber class method callback?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CameraSubscriber  callbacks have two arguments, one for the Image and the second for the CameraInfo- how to add a third argument and bind a value to it within subscribeCamera?

[Using arguments in callback function of image_transport::ImageTransport::subscribeCamera or pass a pointer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/41759/using-arguments-in-callback-function-of-image-transportimagetransportsubscri) was asking the same thing, but the solution was not to pass a parameter, and the other part of the answer did not realize the difference between subscribeCamera and subscribe.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233450/boost-bind-additional-arguments-to-camerasubscriber-class-method-callback?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2016-05-02

Post score: 0

---

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

regarding your reference question, it doesn't matter with boost bind if you replace or add parameters.
It's just a matter of using the placeholders `_1`, `_2`, ... provided by boost for forwarding the original arguments or by providing your own ones.

Here you can find another answer in which two extra parameters are added (next to `_1`): [LINK](http://answers.ros.org/question/232204/passing-multiple-arguments-to-a-callback-c/?answer=232226#post-id-232226).

Regarding the difference between subscribeCamera and subscribe: both functions provide an overload that excepts the a **boost::function** type callback, therefore you can apply boost::bind to both of them.

Refer to the [Code Doc](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1ImageTransport.html) for the overloaded methods:

```
subscribeCamera (const std::string &base_topic, uint32_t queue_size, const CameraSubscriber::Callback &callback, const ros::VoidPtr &tracked_object=ros::VoidPtr(), const TransportHints &transport_hints=TransportHints())

subscribe (const std::string &base_topic, uint32_t queue_size, const boost::function< void(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &)> &callback, const ros::VoidPtr &tracked_object=ros::VoidPtr(), const TransportHints &transport_hints=TransportHints())
```

Here the argument type `CameraSubscriber::Callback` is a typedef for a `boost::function` object accepting both default parameters. Pass your functor created with `boost::bind` here.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer to the referenced question was that `this` was in the wrong place- `this` is an 4th parameter to subscribe variant after the callback class method, but then it moves to inside `boost::bind()` when passing in additional parameters is required.

I wasn't actually making that mistake, but the difference was confusing enough I didn't realize that (and the compilation error was the same)- getting the `_1` and `_2` correct as @croesmann points out was the key.  Here are some different examples.

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>

class CamSub
{
protected:
  bool restrict_size_;

  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
  image_transport::CameraSubscriber sub_1_;
  image_transport::CameraSubscriber sub_2_;
  image_transport::Subscriber sub_3_;

  void imageCallback1(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg,
      const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& ci,
      const int ind) {}
   void imageCallback2(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg,
      const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& ci) {}
   void imageCallback3(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg,
      const int ind) {}
public:
  CamSub();
};

CamSub::CamSub() :
  it_(nh_)
{
  const uint32_t queue_size = 1;
  const int ind = 5;
  sub_1_ = it_.subscribeCamera("image", queue_size,
      boost::bind(&CamSub::imageCallback1, this, _1, _2, ind));
  sub_2_ = it_.subscribeCamera("image", queue_size,
      &CamSub::imageCallback2,
      this);
  sub_3_ = it_.subscribe("image", queue_size,
      boost::bind(&CamSub::imageCallback3, this, _1, ind));
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "cam_sub");
  CamSub cam_sub;
  ros::spin();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1